# Find matches from an array of arrays based on matches condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given I have an array of arrays like the following:

```
var array = [["001"," 003"],["002"," 001"],["001"," 002"],["002"," 001"], ["", "001"]]
```

The condition is the array have to matches with 2 matches or more with each other, then it will store into the new array for the result of it.

I am using the following javascript method, and the method will compare for every single one of arrays within an array.

What I am trying to do is to make the javascript method to not loop every single one of arrays within an array to look for the matches, but it is will be based on the condition stated above (2 matches or more)

**Javascript method:**

```js
var array = [["001"," 003"],["002"," 001"],["001"," 002"],["002"," 001"], ["", "001"]]
console.log(
array.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
  if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && array.every(function(a) {
      return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    })) res.push(v);

  return res;
}, [])
)
```

Result of the array above will be empty, what I expect it to based on the condition stated above (2 matches or more) is:

```
["001", "002", " 001"]
```

Your answer will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, I have updated the question, the result of the above array is empty, but what I expect it to be is not empty, rather than have a `001` and `002` value in a new array. Thanks

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, yes, it should be. The ` 001` should be included in the output as well, since it is matched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For on `O(N)` solution (your current `.every` inside `.reduce` is `O(N^2)`), you can use `reduce` to create an object indexed by strings, whose values are the number of occurrences of that string. Then, `.filter` over the object's `keys` to get those which have at least a count of two:

```js
const input = [["001"," 003"],["002"," 001"],["001"," 002"],["002"," 001"], ["", "001"]];
const obj = input.reduce((a, arr) => {
  arr.forEach((str) => {
    a[str] = (a[str] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return a;
}, {});
const output = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(key => obj[key] >= 2)
console.log(output);
```

Note that because you had two `" 001"` strings in the input, they're included in the output as well.

For an ES5 version, I ran the above through Babel and got:

```js
var input = [["001", " 003"], ["002", " 001"], ["001", " 002"], ["002", " 001"], ["", "001"]];
var obj = input.reduce(function (a, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (str) {
    a[str] = (a[str] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return a;
}, {});
var output = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
  return obj[key] >= 2;
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Alright, got it on this. Thank you very much for your answer! Btw, are those javascript built-in functions restricts to only certain version of browsers? or it supported in all browsers? Thanks!

Comment: The code uses ES6 syntax, support for which is widespread but not uniform, as well as `Object.entries` (similar but later, ES2017). Ideally, use Babel and polyfills in your build process so you can write in the latest and greatest version of the language and transpile down to ES5 automatically in production.

Comment: Any ways to convert it to not use ES6 or ES2017? Since just now I tried in my project and it is not supported for the `Object.entries`, only works in browsers. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Object.keys` instead. I ran the code through Babel, see edit

Comment: Works well now. Thanks a bunch!